# Python: Access index of moving window array that matches current position of array being looped over

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I've coded up a neighbourhood smoothing filter that works on a user supplied 2D array - it works as it is but it could be far faster/less wasteful of memory as currently I am copying the entire input array each time the loop runs through. This will prove a real issue when large arrays are passed in.

The filter is defined as:

```
    import numpy as np
    import os

    def conservative_smooth(array2D, kernel_size = 3):

        stepsize = 1    
        if(kernel_size % 2 != 0 and kernel_size >= 3):
            window = np.ones([kernel_size,kernel_size])
        elif(kernel_size % 2 == 0 or kernel_size < 3):
            print "kernel is even - it needs to be odd and at least of a value of 3"
            os._exit(1)

        nxwind, nywind = array2D.shape

        for i in range(0, nxwind, stepsize):
            for j in range(0, nywind, stepsize):

            # CALCULATE MAX AND MIN RANGES OF ROWS AND COLS THAT CAN BE ACCESSED 
            # BY THE WINDOW
            imin=max(0,i-((kernel_size-1)/2)) 
            imax=min(nxwind-1,i+((kernel_size-1)/2))+1
            jmin=max(0,j-((kernel_size-1)/2))
            jmax=min(nywind-1,j+((kernel_size-1)/2))+1

            # THIS IS THE MOST INEFFICIENT PART OF THE CODE
            array2D_temp = array2D.copy() 
            array2D_temp[i,j] = np.nan

            data_wind=array2D_temp[imin:imax,jmin:jmax]

            centre_value = array2D[i,j]
            max_value = np.nanmax(data_wind) 
            min_value = np.nanmin(data_wind) 

            if(centre_value > max_value):
                centre_value = max_value
            elif(centre_value < min_value):
                centre_value = min_value
            else:
                centre_value = centre_value

            ## Append new centre value to output array
            array2D[i,j] = centre_value         

        return array2D
```

A copy of the entire array is made so that the value at position [i,j] in the array can be temporarily made to NaN  - I can't just copy the moving window regiuon of the array (which would be better) as [i,j] of the main array will not be [i,j] of the moving window array.

A simple "if value at position in moving window == value in main array" condition will not work either as this will fail if values are duplicated.

I've been testing the function using a simple random 10x10 array (`a = np.random.rand(10,10)`)

Has anybody any suggestions?

Comment: Aren't you always setting the centre of the kernel to `nan`? It's not the same as `i, j` but surely it's easy enough to find?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because of the boundaries, the kernel won't always be the same dimension (e.g.  3x3) - in the top left corner for example, the kernel, even though set to 3x3 will only actually be 2x2. I never step outside of the array.

Comment: I would still think it's better to write the exceptions for those edge (ha!) cases than keep copying the whole array, and for all of the full-size samples it's trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this seems to work the same as your original function, with no copying needed.

```
def conservative_smooth(array2D, kernel_size = 3):
    stepsize = 1    
    if(kernel_size % 2 != 0 and kernel_size >= 3):
        window = np.ones([kernel_size,kernel_size])
    elif(kernel_size % 2 == 0 or kernel_size < 3):
        print "kernel is even - it needs to be odd and at least of a value of 3"
        os._exit(1)
    nxwind, nywind = array2D.shape
    for i in range(0, nxwind, stepsize):
        for j in range(0, nywind, stepsize):
            # CALCULATE MAX AND MIN RANGES OF ROWS AND COLS THAT CAN BE ACCESSED 
            # BY THE WINDOW
            imin=max(0,i-((kernel_size-1)/2)) 
            imax=min(nxwind-1,i+((kernel_size-1)/2))+1
            jmin=max(0,j-((kernel_size-1)/2))
            jmax=min(nywind-1,j+((kernel_size-1)/2))+1
            centre_value = array2D[i,j]
            array2D[i,j] = np.nan
            max_value = np.nanmax(array2D[imin:imax,jmin:jmax]) 
            min_value = np.nanmin(array2D[imin:imax,jmin:jmax]) 
            if(centre_value > max_value):
                centre_value = max_value
            elif(centre_value < min_value):
                centre_value = min_value
            else:
                centre_value = centre_value
            ## Append new centre value to output array
            array2D[i,j] = centre_value      
    return array2D
```